# Regex to exclude %3 from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript function that tests a string and validates if it contains letters, numbers, and a few special characters, including the characters `%20` (space) `%27` (apostrophe).

My current RegEx fails as it allows other characters like `%3`

I would like to fail on any match of `%3` in the string. Better still, I would like to only match on `%20` and/or `%27` as a group.

My RegEx is

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\%20\-_:.,!\/\\%27]+$
```

I want this to match

```
Employee%27s%20Saved
```

But fail something like

```
%3Emplo%3yee%27s%20Saved%3
```

Comment: What if there is only one %3 in the middle of a string?

Comment: try `^([0-9a-zA-Z-_:.,!/]|%20|%27)+$`

Answer (score 0):

Update to @MohaMad comment:

```
^(?:[0-9a-zA-Z-_:.,!/\\]|%20|%27)+$
```

By using a non-capturing group it will result with full match only.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a 'non-capturing group' `(?!...)`.

You should try something like this:
`^(\w*(?!\%3)\w*(?:\%27|\%20)\w*)+$`

Check https://regex101.com/r/r89dlA/1